# using GET in a loop

Tags: r, url, get

I am using the following code. I create a list of first names and then generate links to an API for each name and then try to capture the data from each link.

```
mydata$NameGenderURL2 <- paste ("https://gender-api.com/get?name=",mydata$firstname, "&key=suZrzhrNJRvrkWFXAG", sep="")

mynamegenderfunction <- function(x){
  GET(url= mydata$NameGenderURL2[x])
  this.raw.content <- genderdata$content
  this.raw.content <- rawToChar(genderdata$content)
  this.content <- fromJSON(this.raw.content)
  name1[x] <- this.content$name
  gender1[x] <- this.content$gender}


namelist <- mydata$firstname[1:100]
genderdata <- lapply(namelist, mynamegenderfunction)
```

Oddly enough I receive the following message:

```
>Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>Could not resolve host: NA`
```

I tried another API and got the same issue. Any suggestions?

Here is a data sample:
namesurl

```
https://api.genderize.io/?name=kaan
https://api.genderize.io/?name=Joan
https://api.genderize.io/?name=homeblitz
https://api.genderize.io/?name=Flatmax
https://api.genderize.io/?name=BRYAN
https://api.genderize.io/?name=James
https://api.genderize.io/?name=Dion
https://api.genderize.io/?name=Flintu
https://api.genderize.io/?name=Adriana
```

The output that I need is the gender for each link, which would be :Male/Female, Null

Comment: Are there weird characters on your firstname field? You don't seem to be escaping them in any way when building your URL. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hello, I added a sample of data

Comment: This still isn't complete. Too many variables aren't defined. But what do you think is being passed as `x` to your function? Maybe add in a `print(x)` so you can see what's going on. I don't think you are passing the correct value to `GET()`.

Comment: > print(x)
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41
 [42]  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
 [83]  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

Comment: It is strange. Once I try GET(url= mydata$NameGenderURL2[1]) it works but as soon as I give it x it gives me error. (mydata$NameGenderURL2 is the list that I pasted above. you can simply check a link and you will see what the api provides)

Comment: WHen you call `lapply(namelist, mynamegenderfunction)`, you are passing in `namelist`. you are not passing in those numbers. (i'm not sure where you ran that `print(x)`, but I was suggesting you put it inside your `mynamegenderfunction` function.

Comment: Ok, What it prints is a the very first name in my list (i.e Kaan). I just want x to be a number that goes from 1 to 100. Then it simply brings the corresponding URL

Comment: Then don't pass names to `lapply`. If you want numbers, try `lapply(seq_along(namelist), mynamegenderfunction)`